# jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter report visualizer

Tags: junit, jasmine, protractor

I generated this xml after running protractor tests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="Spring Webapp Homepage" errors="0" tests="3" failures="0" time="1.508" timestamp="2014-02-14T15:23:27">
  <testcase classname="Spring Webapp Homepage" name="should get title" time="1.309"></testcase>
  <testcase classname="Spring Webapp Homepage" name="Test Header" time="0.098"></testcase>
  <testcase classname="Spring Webapp Homepage" name="Test Simple Button" time="0.101"></testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

There is an option to output the tests to XML output

```
  onPrepare: function() {
// The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
// needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
// this until inside the onPrepare function.
require('jasmine-reporters');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
  new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('jasmine-results/xmloutput', true, true));
}
```

Is there a way to visualize these reports in the browser that would present them more elegantly than raw XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to visualize these reports in the browser that would present them more elegantly than raw XML?

Actually there is [nosetest-xunit-xslt](https://github.com/niedbalski/nosetest-xunit-xslt).

Note **xsltproc** comes [installed by default](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xsltproc.1.html) on Mac OSX Mavericks.

Take a look at [how the results look like](http://jsfiddle.net/elgalu/R4V9B/embedded/result/)

Update: I'm using a [custom reporter that automates the html conversion](https://github.com/elgalu/singleFileJUnitXmlReporter#you-can-add-an-xslt-transformation)

```
require('./jasmine.single_file_junit_reporter.js');
var junitPath = path.join('junitXMLReport/', '0001');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.singleFileJUnitXmlReporter(
    junitPath, true, true, './nosetests.xslt')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this anwser I managed to get Junit reports on one file, howver I aml not able to install execSync as you mentioned in Github I get this error : gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the P
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\n
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:101:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\no
-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

Comment: I see it compiled a bunch of stuff on my Ubuntu 13.04, for Windows you need to do some extra work, see: https://github.com/mgutz/execSync#install

Comment: btw, did you manage to install **xsltproc** on windows? That's the other dependency to run all these.

Comment: I am now facing issues installing execSync I got error related do C++ compiler.

Comment: regarding xsltproc for windows you need to download it from here and put it inti you ENV path : ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/libxslt-1.1.26.win32.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can use a xUnit html parser to convert your XML files to HTML ones : have a look here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzGG32kz9nc
Then you can integrate you teansformation into your build file